# The meaning of [i] variable in this sitiuation?

Tags: c

Whats the meaning of `[i]` in the following example?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{

  int values[5];
  printf("Enter 5 integers: ");

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
     scanf("%d", &values[i]); // HERE

  }

  printf("Displaying integers: ");

  for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
     printf("%d\n", values[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you add more details to your question? do you just want to know the meaning of access-er [i]?

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Arrays_and_strings

Comment: The book you use for learning purposes should cover that. If you haven't reached that part yet, keep reading. If you don't have a decent book, I suggest you get one. The only way to properly learn C is in a structured manner, and StackOverflow is no replacement to that.

Comment: You need text-book more than SO.

Comment: it's the `i + 1`th element of the array `values` (the first one being indexed at `0`)

Comment: `&values[i]` is exactly equivalent to `values + i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` here is a variable.

In your code, `[i]` acts as the index of `values` and is used to access the element in array `values`.

Edit:

Since there is a `//HERE` comment in your code, im going to assume you would also want what [i] does there. The expression `&value[i]` basically gives the address of `value[i]` ,i.e, the "ith" element of the array.

Comment: Understanding programming is different for different people. I am no expert, but what works for me is referring to various sources on the internet and actually trying to write programs in that language. If you are talking about books, then there is definitely **The C Programming Language by Dennis & Ritchie** or **C Programming, a modern approach by K N King**. But do not depend on textbooks try writing code to understand the language better